# Changing the color of segments in an ASP.NET pie chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, pie-chart

My application requires 5 files[A,B,C,D,E] to be uploaded.

Initially, the pie chart should be in white color with regions named A,B,C,D,E.

As soon as each one is uploaded, a segment of the pie chart should be colored i.e 
5 parts of a pie chart should be colored one by one as each file is uploaded.

When any one of the uploaded files is deleted, that particular part of the chart's color should revert back to white.

I am using the below code:

```
Dictionary<string, int> chartData = new Dictionary<string, int>();
chartData.Add("A", 20);
chartData.Add("B", 20);
chartData.Add("C", 20);
chartData.Add("D", 20);
chartData.Add("E", 20);
this.Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(chartData.Keys, chartData.Values);
this.Chart1.Series[0].Label = "#VALX (#PERCENT)";
Color[] myPalette = new Color[5]{
Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Blue),
Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Green),
Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Red),
Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Orange), 
Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.LightGreen),
};
this.Chart1.Palette = ChartColorPalette.None;
this.Chart1.PaletteCustomColors = myPalette;
```

I have set a flag to 1 when the file is uploaded so I can color the chart and set flag to 0 when the file is deleted so that color can be reverted back to white.

But how can I specify an `if` condition for changing colors of the chart?

Am stuck with this!
Please help!